# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm using Unity + vs code + window 10.

One day, the OmniSharp stop working for no obvious reason. Any help is appreciated!
I've tried re-installing vscode, .net core sdk and c# extension. No luck

```
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\CYF\Unity\BehaviourTreeAI\bhtree\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj'.
c:\CYF\Unity\BehaviourTreeAI\bhtree\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj(0,0)
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.LoggingService.ProcessLoggingEvent(Object buildEvent, Boolean allowThrottling)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.LoggingService.LogProjectEvaluationStarted(BuildEventContext projectEvaluationEventContext, String projectFile)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate()
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(IEvaluatorData`4 data, ProjectRootElement root, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Int32 maxNodeCount, PropertyDictionary`1 environmentProperties, ILoggingService loggingService, IItemFactory`2 itemFactory, IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, BuildEventContext buildEventContext, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 projectConfigurationsInSolution) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 157
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 configurationsInSolution) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 75
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, ProjectLoader loader, Guid sessionId, DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectFile\ProjectFileInfo.cs:line 116
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<LoadProject>b__0() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 304
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 315

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, I think it was an Omnisharp bug.  I just updated to Omnisharp version 1.37.8-beta.2 which looks like it includes a bugfix for this issue, and it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error today...

In my case, although I currently only use VS Code, I still had Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition installed and Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 as well.

After upgrading my VS Code to 1.54.0 (which was released today) and upgrading both Visual Studio Community Edition and Visual Studio Build Tools to the 2019 version, the bug is gone. No more Omnisharp errors, no more issue notification alerts and Intellisense is working again.