# Unity file failed to load: "System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow"

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

Randomly this week I have run into a bug that is preventing me from continuing work and I have no idea how to solve it. I us VS Code for a Unity project and it is telling me

```
OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\jamie\Documents\Unity\Projects\OTHERWOODLY\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
```

The problem is arising from this line in the error log but I will also post the entire error at the end of the post:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried updating .NET and redownloaded the most recent version of Mono. I have also added these settings into my C# settings in VS Code

```
   "omnisharp.path": "latest",
   "omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always",
```

Nothing seems to have fixed it. Really at a loss here, if anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it!

Full Error Message:

```
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\jamie\Documents\Unity\Projects\OTHERWOODLY\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\jamie\Documents\Unity\Projects\OTHERWOODLY\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj'.
c:\Users\jamie\Documents\Unity\Projects\OTHERWOODLY\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj(0,0)
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.LoggingService.ProcessLoggingEvent(Object buildEvent, Boolean allowThrottling)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.LoggingService.LogProjectEvaluationStarted(BuildEventContext projectEvaluationEventContext, String projectFile)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate()
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(IEvaluatorData`4 data, ProjectRootElement root, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Int32 maxNodeCount, PropertyDictionary`1 environmentProperties, ILoggingService loggingService, IItemFactory`2 itemFactory, IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, BuildEventContext buildEventContext, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary(EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 projectConfigurationsInSolution) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 157
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 configurationsInSolution) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 75
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, ProjectLoader loader, Guid sessionId, DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectFile\ProjectFileInfo.cs:line 116
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<LoadProject>b__0() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 304
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 315
 
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: Is this related to [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477357/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-threading-tasks-dataflow-version-4-6-3) (asked 4 hours ago) ?

Comment: @derHugo Looks like it, although the initial solution posted did not solve it for me. I do not have Visual Studio Community or Build Tools and I have updated VS Code to the most recent version. The bug still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had the same issue, and solved it by downloading Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ and then used it to install ".NET desktop build tools". I didn't include any of the optional choices.
Then I restarted VS Code and the error was gone.